$(T^{*})^{+} = (T^{+})^{*}$
I'm trying to prove why $(T^{*})^{+} = (T^{+})^{*}$ only using properties of matrix operations (I'm considering $()^{*}$ and $()^{+}$ operations as well, just to be clear).
However, I assume I cannot use $()^{-1}$ since the pseudoinverse is not always invertible.
I called $(T^{+})^{*} = A$ and tried taking adjoint both sides, taking pseudoinverse both sides and multiplying by $T$ both sides,  but following up did not yield any useful results.
Does anyone has a tip? How should I start my solution?
Note: $T^{+}$ is the pseudoinverse, or Moore-Penrose inverse of $T$, and $T^*$ is the conjugate transpose of T (its Hermitian conjugate).

@TobySaunders-A'Court the pseudoinverse

You should define the operation in your post
